# UWP DataTemplate sometimes shows incorrect view. ( Radomly formatting )

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datatemplate, datacontext

i dont have a mind, how to name this ask, but
I have a code:

```
        <ListView Name="MainWindowLinesInfoListView2" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="MainWindowLinesInfoListView2_ItemClick" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind pk2}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Przystanki">
                    <local:MainWindowLinesInfoSecond />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

So, simply, I want to show content of UserControl: "MainWindowLinesInfoSecond"

Under, is a code of this uc.

```
    public MainWindowLinesInfoSecond()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var a = e.NewValue as Przystanki;

            if (a != null)
                ChangeText(a);
        };

    }

    private void ChangeText(Przystanki przystanek)
    {
        bool bold = false;
        Color color = Colors.White;
        string name = "";

        if (przystanek.wariant)
        {
            color = Colors.Red;
            name = "-- ";
            MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.Margin = new Thickness(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }

        if (przystanek.strefowy)
            color = Colors.Yellow;

        if (przystanek.na_zadanie())
            bold = true;

        if (przystanek.getName() == Pages.MainWindowLinesInfo.line.rozklad[przystanek.rozkladzien_id].track[przystanek.track_id].name)
        {
            color = Colors.Green;
            bold = true;
        }

        MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.Text = name + przystanek.getName();

        if(color != Colors.White)
            MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);

        if (bold)
            MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    }
}
```

And, when i'm running app, sometimes it shows Like A, sometimes Like B, sometimes shows correct, but this is very randomly.

Here's image, to best see of my problem: [image]

So as you see, look at last 3 items. These colors are changing, as they want.. (as my code want)

I dont know why it is, Can anyone help me solve this drama?

**@Update**
Read comment below..

this is code, which works, but specially is just a taking over. (to avoid error)

```
private void ChangeText(Przystanki przystanek)
    {
        bool bold = false;
        Color color = Colors.Navy;
        Thickness margin = new Thickness(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        string name = "";

        if (przystanek.wariant)
        {
            color = Colors.Red;
            name = "-- ";
            margin = new Thickness(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }

        if (przystanek.strefowy)
        {
            color = Colors.Yellow;
        }

        if (przystanek.na_zadanie())
        {
            bold = true;
        }

        if (przystanek.getName() == Pages.MainWindowLinesInfo.line.rozklad[przystanek.rozkladzien_id].track[przystanek.track_id].name)
        {
            color = Colors.Green;
            bold = true;
        }

        MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.Text = name + przystanek.getName();
        MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.Margin = margin;

        MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);

        if (bold)
            MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    }
```

Comment: 1. you didn't provide the full code - so no one can solve your problem without guessing 2. there must be something wrong with your input data, or some other part of the code (that you didn't put here) must be messing with colour settings 3. looking at the ChangeText method I can't see any possibility to have a red text not starting with "--" - that's why I am guessing that the colors are more than once per item

Comment: Rather than using `DataContextChanged` event you should use `Loaded` event and inside it use the `DataContext`

Comment: Only red text is set in this ChangeText; I havent any function that contains any color setters.

I provide the full code, where I did something with this.

It looks, like Color and Margin settings are saved and transfered from one usercontrol to other usercontrol. I cant tell why it is.
I set the breakpoint where i changed a name.

Unbeliveable is that a color of this textblock (default color in xaml is "Navy") was set as Red, but it didnt entered on this `if przystanek.wariant` 

So i solved it by adding at top of `ChangeText` default margin to 0,0,0,0 and default color to Navy

Comment: `Color color = Colors.Navy; Thickness margin = new Thickness(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` and at the end, just set these values.

@Nuwannnz, i tried it before i created this question.

Sorry for my english, is not my primary language.